# Parameters not found for RoR 4 controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a RoR 4 application that I use as a backend API. I am trying to implement pagination when search for users, so I defined the following method in my controller:

```
  def search
    params['page'] = 1 if params['page'].nil?
    pageNumber = params['page']

    params['size'] = 10 if params['size'].nil?
    users = User.filter(filtering_params)
    number_of_users = users.count
    response = {
      number_of_users: number_of_users,
      users: users.paginate(page: pageNumber, size: params['size'])
    }
    respond_with response
  end


  def filtering_params
    params.slice(:_s)
  end
```

The problem is that my application always returns 1 as pageNumber, even when I add a argument ?page=2 for example. Do you guys have an idea what could be wrong?

Comment: Inspect the `params` by putting `raise params.inspect`. I believe it is due to ***string keys***.

Comment: Can you include the view code? And a log of the request, if possible?

Comment: String keys shouldn't matter since Rails stores params in a `HashWithIndifferentAccess` object, which acts like a Hash but is *indifferent* to whether string or symbols are passed as keys.

Comment: @AnthonyE Yes You are right!

Answer (score 0):

```
params['page'] = 1 if params['page'].nil?
pageNumber = params['page']
```

if `params['page']` is nil, `pageNumber` will be an `Integer` whose value is 1

if `params['page']` is '2', `pageNumber` will be a `String` whose value is '2'

Depending on what you do with your argument in the `paginate` method in your User model, it could be the reason why you face this issue.

Maybe you should try to cast it to an Integer before sending it to paginate :

```
pageNumber = params['page'].to_i || 1
```